# Telegram Bot на NodeJS

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Пишу вот бота для Node JS, и пытаюсь написать собственную библиотеку для Telegram

```
const request = require("../../module/request/request.js");

class TelegramAPI {
    constructor(token) {
        this.token = token;
        this.lastUpdateId = undefined;
    }

    buildURL(method) {
        let url = `api.telegram.org/bot${this.token}/${method}`;
        return url;
    }


    getMe() {

    }
    getUpdate() {
        let data = {
            hostname: this.buildURL("getUpdates"),
            body: {
                offset: this.lastUpdateId
            },
            method: 'POST'
        }
        return request(data);
    }


    on(type, callBack) {

        this.getUpdate().then(value => {
            value = value.result;
            if (value[0]) {
                this.lastUpdateId = ++value[value.length - 1].update_id;
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                if (!value[i].edited_message && value[i].message.text && type === "message") {
                    callBack(value[i].message);
                } else if (value[i].edited_message && type === "editMessage") {
                    callBack(value[i].edited_message);
                } else if (!value[i].edited_message && value[i].message.poll && type === "poll") {
                    callBack(value[i].message);
                }
            }
            setTimeout(() => { this.on(type, callBack) }, 1000);
        })

    }

    sendMessage(id, text, settings = { "pagePreview": false, "disNotification": false, "replyMessageId": null }) {

        let url = this.buildURL("sendMessage");


        let data = {
            hostname: url,
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                "chat_id": id,
                "text": text,
                "disable_web_page_preview": settings.pagePreview || false,
                "disable_notification": settings.disNotification || false,
                "reply_to_message_id": settings.replyMessageId,
                "reply_markup": settings.reply_markup
            }
        }
        request(data).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    }

module.exports = TelegramAPI;
```

Использую свой request :

```
const https = require('https');


let options = {
    hostname: undefined,
    path: undefined,
    method: undefined,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        "Content-Length": undefined,
    }
};




let request = function(data) {
    let reg = /[\w.]+\/[\w.]/;

    let body = JSON.stringify(data.body);


    if (reg.test(data.hostname)) {
        options.path = data.hostname.replace(/[\w.]+/, "");
        options.hostname = data.hostname.replace(/\/.+/, "");
    }
    if (data.method === "POST") {
        options.method = "POST";
        options.headers["Content-Length"] = body.length;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const req = https.request(options, (res) => {

                console.log(`Status code: ${res.statusCode}`);

                res.on("data", value => {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(value.toString()));
                })
            });

            req.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error)
            });

            req.write(body);
            req.end();
        })
    }
}

module.exports = request;
```

И вот в чем вопрос... Я не могу создать кнопки в чате используя код ниже. Помогите мне создать кнопки. Каким должен быть запрос?

```
let tg = new tgApi(id);

tg.on("message", (value) => {
    let id = value.chat.id;
    if (value.text === "/start") {
        tg.sendMessage(id, "бла", {
            reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                inline_keyboard: [{ text: "size", callback_data: "2" }]
            }),
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Разрабатываю свое... использую свое... Вопрос: как этим пользоваться? Надо было понимать, во что ввязываешься, либо брать учебный проект полегче, пока опыта не наберется нужного.

Comment: библиотеки [Telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/) здесь хватало за глаза

Comment: пускай пишет, хоть руку набьёт. вон, обработчик `error` в request-е есть, значит не безнадёжен

Comment: @Locker, зачем вопрос удалил? я как раз писал ответ

Comment: @nörbörnën Нашел причину. catch не верно был написан

Comment: да, но не только. клавиатуры прописаны не по формату. короче, вот тебе направление движения https://pastebin.com/8X77wVXW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не правильный формат данных в `inline_keyboard`

В любой непонятной ситуации нас выручает чтение [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)

```
Field
    inline_keyboard
Type
    Array of Array of InlineKeyboardButton
Description
    Array of button rows, each represented by an Array of InlineKeyboardButton objects
```

Тут написано, что `inline_keyboard` - это массив *рядов* кнопок, где каждый ряд представляет собой массив кнопок, т.е. правильный код должен выглядеть так:

```
inline_keyboard: [
    // Ряд 1
    [
        // Ряд 1 Кнопка 1
        { text: "size", callback_data: "2" }
    ]
]
```